# Define a Forward-defined C++ struct by aliasing

Tags: c++, types, struct

I want to write a C-wrapper around an existing C++ codebase. So I need to implement some C-API functions that merely forward their operations to the corresponding C++ methods.

My problem is, I cannot figure out how to implement a forward-defined struct by means of an existing class:

```
//Foo.hpp
namespace myLib {
  struct Foo {
    //some meaningful C++ body
  };
}

//foo.h
//#ifdef __cplusplus etc. left out
extern "C" {
  struct myLib_foo;

  myLib_foo* mkfoo();

  //etc.
}

//foo.cpp
extern "C" {
  #include "Foo.hpp"
  #include "foo.h"

  typedef myLib_foo myLib::Foo;  //this does not work

  myLib_foo* mkfoo() { return new myLib::Foo(); }
}
```

In this situation, the C-API can and shall only work with pointers to `myLib::Foo`, which obviously works well, if I define `myLib_foo` as a new struct inside foo.cpp. I guess it also works, if I define a `struct myLib_foo` somewhere else. Yet, since I want to keep my namespaces manageable, I am searching a way to define `myLib_foo` to be **equivalent** to some existing (and completely defined) struct. This, however does not work, since my compiler refuses the code above with "typedef redefinition with different types". Apparently, it distinguishes between type-aliases and structs.

Is there even a way to achieve what I want or does C++ have no means for real type-aliases?

**edit:**
By the answer below, I figured I can use inheritance plus static_cast:

```
//foo.cpp
extern "C" {
  #include "Foo.hpp"
  #include "foo.h"    

  struct myLib_foo : public myLib::Foo {};  //this does work

  myLib_foo* mkfoo() { return static_cast<myLib_foo*>(new myLib::Foo()); }
}
```

Comment: "I want to write a C-wrapper around an existing C++ codebase."  Kinda going backwards, don't you think?  Why do this?

Comment: @JohnDibling To make it accessible from other languages (or from C++ code compiled by compilers which use different name mangling)? It's actually fairly common to export a C interface to inable interop.

Comment: That is precisely my use case: I want to use C++ features internally (mainly containers and some boost features) but need the universal "pluggability" of a C-library because I want to interface my lib (at least) with fortran and OCaml.

Comment: If the C code will actually use the object (as in dereference the pointer, etc.), that sounds quite dangerous to me. If it will never do so (ie. it will only ever pass the pointer back to your library, and let the library operate on the object), you could instead pass a handle (that uniquely identifies the object) to the C code.

Comment: The C-code won't be able to dereference the pointer safely (because it is of an incomplete type). 
What precisely do you mean by "a handle"? Some kind of index in some manually managed map of objects?

Comment: @choeger : that, or probably more practically, just a `void*` rather than a properly typed pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C code does not ever need a definition of the `struct myLib_foo` that it sees.

It handles it only through pointers and functions.

On the C++ side a simple implementation is a `struct` containing a pointer to the "real" object that it represents. You then define it in the ordinary way (in the C++ code), but of course with the name already established for the C code usage.

If you want to avoid even that little inefficiency, to hand out real object pointers to the C code, well then you have essentially two options:

- `reinterpret_cast`, or
- `static_cast` with the not-quite-C struct as a (possibly empty) base class.

<del>But I would go for the simple implementation of `myLib_foo` as a `struct` with a pointer to the real one.</del> The KISS principle: Keep It Simple, Stupid<sup>*</sup>. On **second thoughts**, to avoid allocation and deallocation issues, and to also avoid a formal dependency on the compiler (even if that would just be academic, a formality), I would go for the `static_cast`. For thinking about what it all entails, this seems simplest.

---

<sup>*: Oh, the last few times I mentioned this principle on SO, those answers were heavily downvoted. That has also happened when I have (correctly) proposed macros as solutions. I think one should be technically honest and ignore the general SO readership, so I mention it anyway.</sup>